# How can I schedule a time for a song to play in Windows Media Player or iTunes?

Tags: windows-7, itunes, windows-media-player, windows-task-scheduler

How can I launch Windows Media Player or iTunes, playing a song, with the Windows task scheduler.

I already know how to create a task and how to trigger it at a given time (launching iTunes / WMP).
But not how to automatically start playing music.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open your Task Scheduler and choose

create basic task

Give the task a name and description and push next

For Trigger choose the option that suits your needs (this one should be self explanitory) Daily at 8:00 AM for example.

For action choose "Start a Program" and choose your MP3 file you want to wake up to

Finish the task.

Test it by running it manually.

I would recommend using Windows Media Player as your default media player to enable it to open when the .MP3 is called. I am unsure if iTunes will play the song as soon as you open it. I can confirm Window Media Player did as I just did a test myself.

Comment: I guess OP would also have to disable any feature that hibernates/turns the computer off after *n* minutes of inactivity.

Comment: yes indeed, I did it. worked fine, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Glad to help. and +1 to Frustrated for his addition. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the path to the music file you want to play as an argument when setting up the scheduled task.

So, instead of starting `itunes.exe` you will start `itunes.exe "c:\mymusic\song.mp3"`

Alternatly you can just specify the music file as the target of the scheduled task and let it figure out what to do, but then it will load your default music player, which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to schedule **more than one music file** with Windows Media Player, then create a new task and set up your trigger type to`on schedule`.

As action, select `Start a program` and insert the following

#### Program/script:

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe"
```

#### Add arguments (optional):

```
"D:\MyMusic\My File1.mp3" "D:\MyMusic\My File2.mp3"
```

Add as many mp3 files as you want. There seems no limit at 255 characters for the arguments list.